# How to manage conference proceedings in BiBTeX?

Tags: bibtex

I am writing my bachelor thesis. I have found an article which is part of a conference's proceedings. It's like a book with a whole collection of articles that were submitted for the conference. I use Mendeley to manage my sources and have added the entire proceedings as "conference proceedings". Mendeley generates the .bib for met. When I quote from one of the articles within the proceedings, i obviously don't want to reference the entire collection, just the one article. Does that mean I need to add both the article and the proceedings to my bib? And how do I then reference the article to the conference proceedings?

Comment: I had a similar problem and decided to change everything to using biblatex  (http://www.ctan.org/topic/biblatex) in conjunction with biber (http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/). This provides an entry type `inproceedings` which you can cite.

Comment: I did come across this option, the downside is that Mendeley only supports BiBTeX. The nice thing about Mendeley is that it extracts the meta information from the PDF you import, or I can import it from the website supplying the article (e.g. Springer). Also it gets additional info if it can find the article on Scholar.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The recommended way is to have a `@proceedings` entry for the "book" (with editor, conference date, venue, ISBN, and so forth) and then `@inproceedings` entries for every paper. In the `@inproceedings` entries you refer via `crossref` to the `@proceedings` entry.

```
@inproceedings{singaravelu:06:eurosys,
  author =       {Singaravelu, Lenin and Pu, Calton and H{\"a}rtig, Hermann and Helmuth, Christian},
  title =        {Reducing TCB complexity for security-sensitive applications: three case studies},
  crossref =     {eurosys:06},
  pages =        {161--174},
  doi =          {10.1145/1217935.1217951},
  keywords =     {application security, trusted computing base},
}

@inproceedings{padioleau:06:eurosys,
  author =       {Yoann Padioleau and Julia L. Lawall and Gilles Muller},
  title =        {Understanding Collateral Evolution in {Linux} Device Drivers},
  crossref =     {eurosys:06},
  pages =        {59--71},
  doi =          {10.1145/1218063.1217942},
  keywords =     {Coccinelle},
}

@proceedings{eurosys:06,
  editor =       {Yolande Berbers and Willy Zwaenepoel},
  title =        "Proceedings of the 6th European Conference on Computer Systems",
  booktitle =    "Proceedings of the 6th European Conference on Computer Systems",
  publisher =    {ACM}
  venue =        {Leuven, Belgium},
  month =        apr,
  year =         {2006},
  isbn =         {1-59593-322-0},
}
```

With this structure, if you cite a paper (`@inproceedings` entry), BibTeX will either import the missing information from the crossref'ed `@proceedings` entry into the paper's entry inside the bibliography or, if more than two papers from the same proceedings are referenced, save some space by putting the `@proceedings` entry itself into the bibliography and refer from the paper's entries to them.

(The threshold of two is the default; this is configurable on the `bibtex` command line with the `-min-crossrefs=NUMBER` option.)

**Caveats**

- With many `bibtex` implementations, the `@proceedings` entry has to be placed behind the respective `@inproceedings` entires in the bib-file. Otherwise it is not found.
- The duplication of `title` and `booktitle` is a strange necessity. If BibTex imports the missing field into the `@inproceedings` entry, it needs the `booktitle` field. If the `@proceedings` entry is itself referenced (either implicitly through the threshold or explicitly by a `\cite` command) it needs the `title` field.
- With BibLaTeX, the principle remains the same. In combination with `biber`, we can get rid of the above idiosyncrasies, though.

Comment: Thnx! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: When I `\cite` an article with `pages={3310--3317}`, do I cite pages 1-7 in text or 3310-3317? Since it's an `inproceedings` entry, the page numbers should refer to the article itself, shouldn't they?

Comment: @kim366: I am not sure I understand your question: Technically, the page numbers refer to what was given in the `pages` field. If both, the `@inproceedings` and the `@proceedings` entry have a pages field, the "later" wins,  depending on where you do insert the `crossref`.

Comment: Is it possible to put the link on the name of the book in @inproceedings, just like usual articles in Bibtex? When I include DOI in the Bibtex file, it appears as DOI which is not nice.

Comment: @QGravity: You don't have to use `@proceedings`. Just put everything into the `@inproceedings` entry and you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate `@inproceedings` entry for each article from the proceedings. If you have more than one article from the same proceedings you can separate out the common things in a single `@proceedings` and refer to it using a `crossref` field, using the key from the `@proceedings` entry. For example:

```
@proceedings{saicsit98,
  booktitle={Proceedings of SAICSIT'98},
  year={1998}
}

@inproceedings{machanick1998design,
  title={Design of a scalable video on demand architecture},
  author={Machanick, Philip},
  crossref={saicsit98},
  pages={211--217},
}

@inproceedings{machanick1998disk,
  title={Disk Delay Lines},
  author={Machanick, Philip},
  crossref={saicsit98},
  pages={142--144},
}
```

This saves you repeating the common details of the conference like its name and year. The purpose of `booktitle` is to name the proceedings; `title` is the title of the article. Doing it with the `@proceedings` first worked for me; some versions of BiBTeX require it last. If you need to cite the whole proceedings the minimum extra thing you need as an editor field so it can be sorted correctly in the reference list or bibliography. For some reason the book title is not picked up so you also need the `title` (same as `booktitle`). I seldom do that so for me the minimalist version given here works.

More [here](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf).

Comment: All of this was already given in the answer from 2013.