# Bibliography is not showing 'publisher' for an entry. What is wrong here?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

[image]

What is wrong with the following code? It is not printing the publisher name in 2nd bibliographic entry. What is wrong here? I am using TexStudio with MikConsole.

main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document} 
    test example   
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography      
\end{document}
```

ref.bib file:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@article{understandingPrivacy,
    author      = "Solove Daniel J",
    title       = "Understanding privacy",
    publisher   = "Harvard University Press",
    year        = "2008",
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}
```

Comment: Is the entry "understandingPrivacy" really a journal article? It looks more like a book. --> Change `@article{understandingPrivacy,` to `@book{understandingPrivacy,`

Answer (score 2):

The reference type of the second entry should be `@book` rather than `@article`. The entry type `@article` should be used *exclusively* for pieces published in (scholarly) journals.

In addition, since the author's surname is `Solove`, you should write the argument of the `author` field either as `"Solove, Daniel J."` (note the comma) or as `"Daniel J. Solove"`.

In short, rewrite the entry as follows:

```
@book{understandingPrivacy,
    author      = "Solove, Daniel J.",
    title       = "Understanding Privacy",
    publisher   = "Harvard University Press",
    year        = "2008",
}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your fine answer to point out a second mistake in the `understandingPrivacy` entry: the incorrect syntax for the author's full name. This issue was admittedly not raised (and possibly not even noticed!) by the OP, but it should be pointed out and fixed nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, what if it had been a conference paper! How to include reference of a conference paper?

Comment: That really depends upon whether (and where) the conference paper has been published (for instance, see https://getproofed.com/writing-tips/apa-referencing-how-to-cite-a-conference-paper/). If it's been published in some proceedings or an edited volume, then use the `@proceedings` and `@inproceedings` reference types (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123252/how-to-manage-conference-proceedings-in-bibtex). If it's unpublished, there's no standard way to do it - though here's a helpful thread: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7288.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much .